# How to create a Dropdown in a html table with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html table with the id "myTable" and an array "myArray". I would like to make a dropdown in the table with the values of myArray. How can I do that?

I would need to iterate through the array and than make a dropdown, but how? Is there a jQuery way to do this on an easy way?

```
 <script>
             var myArray = ["one", "two", "three"];

             var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

             var row = table.insertRow(0);

             var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
             var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
             var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);


             cell1.innerHTML = "something";
             cell2.innerHTML = "something else";
             cell3.innerHTML = myArray; //This should be a dropdown
    </script>
```

Comment: There is no easier way. You have to iterate your array and append a new `<option>` to your select for each value. It's easy.

Comment: You're literally almost there ..  one `for` loop and presto!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery doesn't save you much effort here.  This would be a pure JavaScript solution for comparison:

```js
var myArray = ["one", "two", "three"];
var dropdown = "<select>\n";
myArray.forEach(addOption);
dropdown += "</select>";
document.getElementById("dropdown").innerHTML = dropdown;

function addOption(item, index) {
  dropdown += "\t<option value='" + item + "'>" + item + "</option>\n";
}
```

```html
<div id='dropdown'></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since jQuery is tagged there, so you can do it like below:-

Working snippet:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var myArray = ["one", "two", "three"];
  var option = '';
  $.each(myArray,function(key,value){
    option += "<option value"+key+">"+value+"</option>";
  });
  $('#select').html(option);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="select"></select>
```

Comment: ^1 for mentioning the `jQuery` tag --  and for using  `.each()`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution with jQuery if you do not mind to use it.

```js
             var myArray = ["one", "two", "three"];

             var $table = $("#myTable");
             var $tr = $('<tr>');
             $tr.html('<td>something</td><td>something else</td><td class="options"></td>');
             
             var $select = $('<select>');
             for (var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
              $('<option>').html(myArray[i]).appendTo($select);
             }
             $select.appendTo($tr.find('.options'));
             $tr.appendTo($table);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"></table>
```